# Unable to compile class for JSP - version Apache Tomcat/7.0.69

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, tomcat7

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /test/test.jsp
com.infosys.bankaway.icici.util.EncryptDecryptUtil cannot be resolved to a type

```
1: <%@ page import="com.infosys.bankaway.icici.util.*" %>
2: <%
3: com.infosys.bankaway.icici.util.EncryptDecryptUtil encDecUtil;
```

We are getting above error. Are there any rules to import third party package ?
are there any configuration changes  required?

Comment: did you add the required jars?

Comment: No there is no rule, you can just import like any other library but don't forget to put the required jar in your WEB-INF/lib folder